# Action defined inside the struts.xml is getting called and the actions present in the Action packages are not getting called

Tags: java, struts2, jboss, annotations, jboss7.x

I am migrating my application server from Jboss 4.2 to 7.1. I am getting the following error in the Struts configuration. `Action` defined inside the `struts.xml` is getting called and the actions present in the `Action` packages are not getting called. I am also posting my `Action`, `struts.xml` and stacktrace:

```java
13:56:06,503 ERROR [org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2) Could not find action or result: There is no Action mapped for namespace / and action name loginValidate. - [unknown location]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxy.prepare(DefaultActionProxy.java:178) [xwork-core-2.1.6.jar:]
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.prepare(StrutsActionProxy.java:61) [struts2-core-2.1.8.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(StrutsActionProxyFactory.java:39) [struts2-core-2.1.8.1.jar:]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(DefaultActionProxyFactory.java:47) [xwork-core-2.1.6.jar:]
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:478) [struts2-core-2.1.8.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77) [struts2-core-2.1.8.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91) [struts2-core-2.1.8.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:147) [spring-orm-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76) [spring-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619) [rt.jar:1.6.0_20]
```

**My `Struts.xml`:**

```xml
<constant name="struts.convention.action.packages" value="com.infotech.project.web.action" />
<constant name="struts.convention.package.locators" value="actions,action" />

 
<constant name="struts.convention.result.path" value="/WEB-INF/jsp" />

<constant name="struts.convention.default.parent.package" value="project" />


<package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default,json-default" />
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />

<package name="project"
    extends="struts-default,json-default,jfreechart-default, jasperreports-default"
    namespace="/">
          <!-- more action names goes here -->
     </package>
```

**My `LoginAction.java`:**

```java
package com.infotech.project.web.action;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionContext;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Result(type="json")
public class LoginAction extends ActionSupport implements SessionAware {


@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@SkipValidation
@Action(value = "/loginValidate", results = { @Result(name = "success", params = {"ignoreHierarchy","false"}) })
public String validateUserLogin() { 
     // validation code goes here
 }
    }
```

**After Updating to Struts 2.3.4:**

```log
ERROR [com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.finder.ClassFinder] (MSC service thread 1-1) Unable to read class [com.lntinfotech.virtuoso.web.action.DttjoinAction]: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/opensymphony/xwork2/util/finder/ClassFinder$InfoBuildingVisitor
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.finder.ClassFinder.readClassDef(ClassFinder.java:782) [xwork-core-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.finder.ClassFinder.<init>(ClassFinder.java:165) [xwork-core-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
    at org.apache.struts2.convention.PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.findActions(PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.java:386) [struts2-convention-plugin-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
    at org.apache.struts2.convention.PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.buildActionConfigs(PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.java:344) [struts2-convention-plugin-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
    at org.apache.struts2.convention.ClasspathPackageProvider.loadPackages(ClasspathPackageProvider.java:53) [struts2-convention-plugin-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:245) [xwork-core-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:66) [xwork-core-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:390) [struts2-core-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:437) [struts2-core-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:74) [struts2-core-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:51) [struts2-core-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:447) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:3269) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3865) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [rt.jar:1.6.0_20]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [rt.jar:1.6.0_20]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619) [rt.jar:1.6.0_20]
```

Comment: The @SkipValidation annotation could be useful instead of defining custom interceptor stack that allows to exclude some methods from validation.

Comment: BTW `com.lntinfotech.virtuoso.web.action.DttjoinAction` is not mentioned in the config. And noclassdeffound exceprion means that this action doesn't exist and you have wrong configuration.

Comment: com.lntinfotech.virtuoso.web.action is the Action Package which contains all my Action classes . xwork-core 2.3.4 is not recognozing the Action classes leading to Action not defined error .. Any Solutions?

Comment: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/opensymphony/xwork2/util/finder/ClassFinder$InfoBuildingVisitor error does that mean problem in the xwork-core 2.3.4 jar ??

Comment: nope, the problem in the action configuration. Remove configuration and everything will work fine, don't forget to accept answer.

Comment: I have removed the configuration as u said . but still i am getting the above trace. i have 30 Action classes under that Action package and for each class im getting that java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError error..

Comment: Check for description in the javadoc for java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem may come from the fact that you have two packages on the same namespace. Try removing one package, or to change the namespace of one of them (maybe the first, that is empty)

---

EDIT:

It is the **[Bug WW-3662:](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-3662)** (Struts2) convention-plugin not work in jboss-7.0.0

As you can read, it is resolved in latest releases.

So, if you need to migrate to JBoss 7, you need to migrate to Struts 2.3.3 or higher.

Hope that helps

Comment: No i tried both by removing the default package as well as changing the namespace of the default package both dint work :(

Comment: yes i upgraded my struts version to 2.3.4 and after that i am getting the class not defined error.I have updated the question with the new stack trace

Comment: now probably is due to multiple versions of the same library on your project... check it out carefully

Comment: Hi Andrea found the solution after upgrading to strtus 2.3.4 it required asm 3.3 jar but asm 1.5.3 was in my lib folder after i changed that error went away thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `@Namespace("/")` for your action. and use `@Action(value = "loginValidate"` so your action could be found from the action mapping. If still doesn't help try to **remove**

```
<constant name="struts.convention.action.packages" value="com.infotech.project.web.action" />
<constant name="struts.convention.package.locators" value="actions,action" />


<constant name="struts.convention.result.path" value="/WEB-INF/jsp" />
```

**EDIT:**

If you use convention plugin why do you have packages in the struts.xml. Remove all that duplicate configuration from the XML. Use `@ParentPackage("default")` or

```
<constant name="struts.convention.default.parent.package" value="default"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow Roman C's instruction and add the following line to your struts.xml

```
<constant name="struts.convention.package.locators.basePackage" value="com.infotech.project.web.action"/>
```

I suggest using config-browser plugin to make sure your annotated actions are successfully loaded before you invoke them.